# Proving the existence of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, proof-writing, solution-verification

Suppose that $V$ is a non-zero vector space and $T: V \rightarrow V$. Show that there is an ordered basis for $V$ s.t. $A$, the matrix representation of $T$ in the basis has a first column that is either $(c\space0 ...\space0)^T$ for some $c \in F$, or $(0\space 1\space 0 ...\space 0)^T$.

My attempt:
Suppose that $B = {v_1, ..., v_n}$ is a basis for $V$ s.t. $T(v_j) \in$ span$(v_1, ..., v_{j+1})$. Then, the first column of A is of the form:

$$A = (a_{11}\space a_{21}\space 0 ...\space0)^T$$

where $aij$ is the $ij$ entry of A.

The first column is given by $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_1) = a_{11}v_1 + a_{21}v_2$. Therefore, there is an ordered basis for $V$ s.t. $A$ has a first column that is either $(c\space0 ...\space0)^T$ where $c = a_{11}$ or $(0\space 1\space 0 ...\space 0)^T$.

I don't think what I've done above is right. Nevertheless, I haven't done a proof of showing the existence of a basis before, so I was hoping someone can go over the proof above and let me know if and where I've made a mistake(s). Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first column of $A$ in that basis is of the form you claim, then you need either $a_{21} = 0$ or $a_{11}=0$ and $a_{21}=1$ to solve the problem.

Here's how I would do this problem. There are two cases: $T$ has an eigenvalue or it does not. If $T$ has an eigenvalue $c$ then by definition there is some $0 \neq v \in V$ such that $Tv = c v$. Extend $v$ to an ordered basis where it is the first element, so $(v=v_1, \dots, v_n)$. As $Tv_1=cv_1$, we therefore have that the first column of $A$ is $(c, 0, \dots, 0)^t$.

On the other hand, suppose $T$ does not have an eigenvalue. Then for any $0 \neq v \in V$, $Tv$ is not a scalar multiple of $v$. Thus, $\{v, Tv\}$ is linearly independent. It can therefore be extended to an ordered basis $(v=v_1,Tv=v_2, \dots, v_n)$. Then as $Tv_1=v_2$, the first column of $A$ is $(0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)^t$.

By the way, it's a bit pedantic but you do need to specify that $\dim V > 1$ otherwise this makes no sense.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense but how did you come up with eigenvalues to use in proving the existence of a potential basis?

Comment: If $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$ is the basis for which $A$ is the matrix representation of $T$, then saying that the first column of $A$ is $(c, 0, \dots, 0)^t$ is precisely saying that $Tv_1=cv_1$, i.e. that $v_1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $c$. This is how the matrix representation is defined. I used similar reasoning for the other case.

Comment: Oh I see! I also just now noticed that $T$ maps $V$ to $V$ which should have hinted at using eigenvalues. In any case, thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!